# Why does default AsyncController's index not work in Grails?

Tags: asynchronous, grails

I came back to Grails after [oh so many] years, and was happy to find the Async Controllers.
I wanted to experiment, so I have created a very simple domain class:

```
class ClientDevice implements AsyncEntity<ClientDevice> {

    int width
    int height

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And generated the default async controller and views.
Upon running the app using `grails run-app`, I've browsed to `http://localhost:8080/clientDevice/index`, and I'm getting HTTP Error 500.

I've looked at the logs - nothing.

The `http://localhost:8080/clientDevice/create` page works fine, but saving new `clientDevice` does not work.

I'm using the default development devDb H2 memory database.
This is happening on Grails 3.3.3 with Java 1.8_161

Any tips? I was really looking forward to trying the async stuff.

Comment: What is in your controller?

Comment: I see now you are using the default generated controller. Sorry for the noise.